# Objects are not valid as a React child with Styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to render an image. Here's my code:

`Accordion.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ArrowTemplate from "./ArrowTemplate";

function Accordion() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ArrowTemplate arrowType={"BlackDown"} styles={""}/>
            {/*<ArrowTemplate arrowType={"BlackUp"}/>*/}
            {/*<ArrowTemplate arrowType={"WhiteDown"} styles={"background:black"}/>*/}
            {/*<ArrowTemplate arrowType={"WhiteUp"} styles={"background:black"}/>*/}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Accordion;
```

`ArrowTemplate.jsx`

```
import BlackDownArrowSVG from './svgs/black-down-arrow.svg';
import WhiteDownArrowSVG from './svgs/white-down-arrow.svg';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

ArrowTemplate.propTypes = {
    arrowType: PropTypes.string,
    styles: PropTypes.string,
};

function ArrowTemplate(props) {
    const {arrowType, styles} = props;
    switch (arrowType) {
        case "WhiteDown":
            return (
                styled.img.attrs({
                    src: WhiteDownArrowSVG,
                })`${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
            );
        case "BlackDown":
            return (
                styled.img.attrs({
                    src: BlackDownArrowSVG,
                })`${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
            );
        case "WhiteUp":
            return (
                styled.img.attrs({
                    src: WhiteDownArrowSVG,
                })`transform: rotate(180deg); ${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
            );
        case "BlackUp":
            return (
                styled.img.attrs({
                    src: BlackDownArrowSVG,
                })`transform: rotate(180deg); ${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
            );
        default:
            throw("You need to pass arrowType");
    }
}

export default ArrowTemplate;
```

The SVG paths are correct.

As the error I get this:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, displayName, attrs, componentStyle, foldedComponentIds, styledComponentId, target, withComponent, warnTooManyClasses, toString}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>       in ArrowTemplate (at Accordion.jsx:7)

When I console.log  I get a long object. But I get a similar object when I console.log the example code from the [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics):

```
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//This renders with no problem
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import BlackDownArrowSVG from './svgs/black-down-arrow.svg';
import WhiteDownArrowSVG from './svgs/white-down-arrow.svg';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

ArrowTemplate.propTypes = {
    arrowType: PropTypes.string,
    styles: PropTypes.string,
};

function ArrowTemplate(props) {
    const {arrowType, styles} = props;
    let StyledArrowTemplate;

    switch (arrowType) {
        case "WhiteDown":
          StyledArrowTemplate = (
            styled.img.attrs({
                src: WhiteDownArrowSVG,
            })`${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
          );
        break;
        case "BlackDown":
          StyledArrowTemplate = (
            styled.img.attrs({
                src: BlackDownArrowSVG,
            })`${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
          );
        break;
        case "WhiteUp":
          StyledArrowTemplate = (
            styled.img.attrs({
                src: WhiteDownArrowSVG,
            })`transform: rotate(180deg); ${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
          );
        break;
        case "BlackUp":
          StyledArrowTemplate = (
            styled.img.attrs({
                src: BlackDownArrowSVG,
            })`transform: rotate(180deg); ${styles !== null ? styles : ""}`
          );
        break;
        default:
            throw("You need to pass arrowType");
    }

    return <StyledArrowTemplate />;
}

export default ArrowTemplate;
```

EDIT:

Apologies for the lack of initial lack of explanation!

So the reason this error occurs is when you return some sort of Object in your JSX code. In this case it is `styled.img.attrs`. So to get around this, we declare a variable which will then be set to be the styled component inside one of the cases, depending on what props you provide to the `ArrowTemplate` component, and return it at the end of the function.

This way, you are basically creating a `StyledComponent` as you normally would, but in a dynamic way.

Comment: Ok this works. Can you add an explanation why? Also please add break after each case, and I'll pick as best

Answer (score 7):

If you come across this when declaring a styled component, you could be forgetting the template literals at the end of the declaration. So

```
const AppContentWithSideBar = styled((props) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Router>
        <SideBarWrapper>
          <SideBar />
        </SideBarWrapper>
        <MainWrapper>
          {props.children}
        </MainWrapper>
      </Router>
    </Wrapper>
  );
});
```

should be

```
const AppContentWithSideBar = styled((props) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Router>
        <SideBarWrapper>
          <SideBar />
        </SideBarWrapper>
        <MainWrapper>
          {props.children}
        </MainWrapper>
      </Router>
    </Wrapper>
  );
})``;
```

Comment: For me it was deleting the `()` part after `attrs` but accidentally leaving the `.attrs` part

Comment: You save my time ) Such small detail, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Lindsay's above answer probably works fine, but I think it would make even more sense not to have a switch case, but to return a single component and pass in your conditions as props, doing your conditional logic in the definition of the styled component, i.e. something like...

```
const ArrowTemplate = styled.div`
  src: ${props => props.color === Black ? BlackDownArrowSVG : WhiteDownArrowSVG};
  ${props => props.direction === Down ? transform: rotate(180) : null }
  etc...
`;
```

(not sure I have the above syntax exactly right, but this is the basic idea)

and

```
<ArrowTemplate color={Black} direction={Up} src={src} />
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const Button = styled.button`
    font: inherit;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #8b005d;
    color: white;
    background: #8b005d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    cursor: pointer;
`
```

You are getting this error because you are storing the value in the function instead of the variable. let me give you an example and let you know.

This will work for you.

Comment: Hi @RudreshOza, please use code blocks and not images to answer. Also you are answering an old question without adding any useful information or explaination on the topic: where this code should be employed or why should it be useful? Please consider to expand your answer or retract it

Comment: Hi, @DDomen thanks for your suggestion I've made changes I know this question is very old but still I found that the answers which were there were not appropriate that's why I thought of putting a solution for the same.